# client-server application design patterns

Tags: python, design-patterns, server-side

I'm building both a client and server side application. it is a messaging/communication program. Currently the client side application is designed to accept either markup and/or text files that represent the requested information, as well as accept a streamed/downloaded file which represents message content (images, videos, etc), and also performs these processes in reverse in the case of sending messages, requesting lists, etc.

The server side of the application consists of python scripts and modules that read, write, and store files and information based on the requested action. The server itself would have to communicate with external dependencies outside of the python libraries (postgresql).

How could I deploy this program in a way that allows it to communicate via the requests and responses of HTTP and be serviceable by the client application programs?

Comment: Are you using any particular python framework?

Comment: Sounds like either use Django or Flask to provide a REST API to the outside and abstract the database on the server side - these frameworks will do most of the design decisions for you

Comment: If you're searching for guidance on how to build this using python, you have web-frameworks like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [Pyramid](http://www.pylonsproject.org/), [Falcon](http://falconframework.org/) (etc...). For the client you can use [requests lib](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (and btw the client application programs, if written in python, can use HTTP through requests lib). If you also want some guidance on how to build a client application program take a look at [kivy](http://kivy.org/#home).

Comment: i'm pretty much looking for a "full stack" server solution. Pretty much any software (or collection of) that I can deploy on a PaaS server and allow my client application to be fully functional on whatever platform with an internet connection. 
Currently I've looked Pyramid, and the combination of Gunicorn and Nginx, but am still kind of unclear on how to implement them with my particular python scripts and how they would connect/service an IP connection.